# How would you translate ご褒美のケーキ?

Tags: translation

I was watching the video and the guy won a cake, so he said 「ご褒美のケーキ」

so I was wondering how should I translate this in English?

I know that

> ご褒美 = prize, reward
>
> ケーキ = cake

but simply putting them together is quite odd to me

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer that I was looking for so I will post it here.

> ご褒美のケーキ = Winner's Cake

@Chocolateさん's answer has a correct meaning too, but it's just that in this context it will be odd, if the guy said "(I won/got) a cake as a prize!"

Answer (score 5):

The の here is the appositive case (同格), e.g. 息子**の**太郎 (my son Taro)

> ご褒美**の**ケーキ

So I think it'd literally be like "(I won/got) a cake as a prize!"